# How to read XML data from a URL by using Visual C#

Tags: c#, xml

There are 1304 KeyFamily groups.

As an example: 

Quarterly National Accounts in XML.

The task is to combine all these 1304 families in one txt file using id and Name

This is the way how it must look like in txt file:
QNA|Quartily National Accounts
PAT_IND|.....
....|....

```
 while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    Console.Write(reader.Value);

                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) 
                        Console.Write(reader.Value + "'");
                    Console.Write(">");
                    Console.WriteLine(">");
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text: 
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement: 
                    Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(">");
                    break;
            }
        }

<KeyFamily id="QNA" agencyID="OECD">...</KeyFamily>
<KeyFamily id="PAT_IND" agencyID="OECD">...</KeyFamily>
<KeyFamily id="SNA_TABLE11" agencyID="OECD">...</KeyFamily>
<KeyFamily id="EO78_MAIN" agencyID="OECD">
<Name xml:lang="en">
Economic Outlook No 78 - December 2005 - Annual Projections for OECD Countries
</Name>
```

Comment: need to know the structure of xml file.. could you post a link or show a sample of xml (with root and node)

Answer (score 0):

Try following which uses xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        const string XML_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string URL = "https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/all";
        const string TEXT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.CheckCharacters = false;
            //XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XML_FILENAME, settings);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URL, settings);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(TEXT_FILENAME);
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "KeyFamily")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("KeyFamily");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement keyFamily = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);

                    List<string> columns = new List<string>();
                    columns.Add((string)keyFamily.Attribute("id"));
                    //string agencyID = (string)keyFamily.Attribute("agencyID");
                    columns.AddRange(keyFamily.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Name").Select(x => (string)x));

                    writer.WriteLine(string.Join("|", columns));
                }
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  Please follow the link where there is xml with root and node: https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/all

Comment: The xml is not valid.  Contains an ampersand : <Name xml:lang="en">Fisheries R&D expenditures</Name>.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: I updated code to work with XML link.  If works if called from URL, but fails if I put the XML into a file.

Comment: Could you please explain how I can have an output only in English: xml:lang="en"? Thank you very much!

Comment: Change one line : columns.AddRange(keyFamily.Elements().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "Name") && ((string)x.Attributes().First() == "en")).Select(x => (string)x));