# How to store a very large file into a database record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

A client uses our web application to parse a XML file for a database. Then uses the information from the XML file from the database for various other things. I am as of now stream reading and stream writing the file. When the files were smaller, they used to be parsed into a string then inserted into a the database record. The problem is the file is so large that computers don't have enough RAM to process a string that large, how can I process this file and still store it in a database?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(outputPath))
                {
                    string line = string.Empty;
                    bool save = false;
                    using (var sWriter = new StreamWriter(inputPath))
                    {
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
                            if (line.Contains("<SaveDataFromScout>"))
                            {
                                sWriter.WriteLine("<SaveDataFromScout>");
                                save = true;
                                continue;
                            }
                            else if (line.Contains("</SaveDataFromScout>"))
                            {
                                sWriter.WriteLine(line);
                                save = false;
                            }

                            if (save)
                            {
                                if (line.Contains("ELEMENT TEXT"))
                                    line = line.Replace("ELEMENT TEXT", "ELEMENTTEXT");

                                sWriter.WriteLine(line);
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }

                //string workbookXML = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(outputPath);

                transactionID = DAC.ExecuteScalar
                    (
                        db.ConnectionString,
                        "dbo.cwi_InsertTransaction",
                        new SqlParameter("@TransactionTypeID", transactionTypeID),
                        new SqlParameter("@UploadedFileName", fileDataLink),
                        //new SqlParameter("@UploadedFileXml", workbookXML),
                        new SqlParameter("@CurrentUserID", CurrentUser.UserID)
                    );
```

Do you see the commented out code where it previously was converted into a string to be parsed into the database? Well, this works, but it does not work for files that are around 888MB large.

Comment: Make XML file smaller. I am sure overall performance will improve dramatically in other parts of the program as well.

Comment: This is not an option. it uploads under 6 minutes so performance is not really an issue.

Comment: The only way of reading a huge xml is using XmlReader.  See example I did earlier today : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55705586/how-to-read-xml-data-from-a-url-by-using-visual-c-sharp/55705900#comment98105005_55705900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the file directly into SQL Server, XML column type using bulk load:

```
INSERT INTO T(XmlCol)  
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(  
   BULK 'c:\SampleFolder\SampleData3.txt',  
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

More documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017